# How to end the excerpt with a sentence rather than a word?

Tags: posts, excerpt, read-more

Here is the excerpt of the post on my home page. I want to end the excerpt with a sentence. In this case it is ' opportunities. '. I know how to modify the length but it won't do what i want.

[image]

Here is excerpt from other website. Here you see excerpt ending with a proper sentence unlike the above which ends with the first word of next sentence 'Proactively'.

[image]

**After Implementing the [solution by G.M.](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/108857/28040) :-**

[image]

Comment: Please explain your issue better than that. From the answers and comments on them, it's hard to understand what you want to achieve.

Comment: @kaiser I have updated the details.

Comment: @Mohit have you tryed my code?

Comment: Yes, excerpt ends with sentence but 'Read More' is gone.

Comment: @G.M. Alright i have to add the read more in the return.

Comment: @Mohit see the edit. After kaiser comment I've edited the code to rune on save/update so it doesn't slow down page view if you have some post on the page.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This requires PHP 5.3+ (WP requires PHP 5.2.4+)

```
add_filter('get_the_excerpt', 'end_with_sentence');

function end_with_sentence($excerpt) {
  $allowed_end = array('.', '!', '?', '...');
  $exc = explode( ' ', $excerpt );
  $found = false;
  $last = '';
  while ( ! $found && ! empty($exc) ) { 
    $last = array_pop($exc);
    $end = strrev( $last );
    $found = in_array( $end{0}, $allowed_end );
  }
  return (! empty($exc)) ? $excerpt : rtrim(implode(' ', $exc) . ' ' .$last);
}
```

### Edit

After @kaiser comment I try to run this on save/update to prevent page slow down on showing a lot of posts. This should be tested

```
add_filter('wp_insert_post_data', 'end_with_sentence_on_save', 20, 2);

function end_with_sentence_on_save($data, $postarr) {
  if ( ! empty( $data['post_content'] ) && $data['post_status'] != 'inherit' && $data['post_status'] != 'trash' ) {
    $text = strip_shortcodes( $data['post_content'] );
    $text = apply_filters('the_content', $text );
    $text = str_replace(']]>', ']]&gt;', $text );
    $excerpt_length = apply_filters('excerpt_length', 55);
    $data['post_excerpt'] = wp_trim_words($text, $excerpt_length, '');
  } else {
    return $data;
  }
  $allowed_end = array('.', '!', '?', '...');
  $exc = explode(' ', $data['post_excerpt']);
  $found = false;
  $last = '';
  while ( ! $found && ! empty($exc) ) { 
    $last = array_pop($exc);
    $end = strrev( $last );
    $found = in_array( $end{0}, $allowed_end );
  }
  if (! empty($exc)) $data['post_excerpt'] = rtrim(implode(' ', $exc) . ' ' .$last);
  return $data; 
}
```

Comment: sure about that: `$end{0}`? Btw, you could just return or `break` when something is found. Additional note: It might better to that when saving the post, so it's not regenerated during runtime, which can get quite slow if you're displaying lots of posts.

Comment: @kaiser cite: *Strings may also be accessed using braces, as in $str{42}, for the same purpose.* [php.net docs](http://www.php.net/manual/it/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.nowdoc) To find something I had to find last char of last string. Using `$found` I break the cycle **and** check last string, so no need to `break`.

Comment: Completely missed that it's a `while` checking for `false`. +1

Comment: @kaiser +1 for the second part of your comment, now I edit the code to run on save

Comment: @G.M.It's not working after the edit.

Comment: @Mohit, of course, there was a bug... now it should works. Note that you have to update your post.

Comment: @G.M. This code is causing some problem in the backend. Problem is related to admin login, it won't let me publish the post, instead it shows 'submit for review'.

Comment: @Mohit, Once you accepted first answer (and it works) I republished it and in a edit I try to adjust the function that run on save. Try it again...

Comment: @Mohit also function on save seems to work for me. You can have both functions if you want, so old posts do not need to be updated... but update all is better for performance.

Comment: There is a bug, it should be $excerpt instead of $data['post_excerpt'] in the first version.

Comment: Sure @jessica was a bad edit (in the original version it was ok). Thanks, fixed.

Comment: original answer's return statement should start `if (empty($exc))`

Answer (score 3):

Here is my version, keeping all html tags and also trimming the content after the last word in of a sentence

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'pietergoosen_custom_wp_trim_excerpt' ) ) : 

    function pietergoosen_custom_wp_trim_excerpt($pietergoosen_excerpt) {
    global $post;
    $raw_excerpt = $pietergoosen_excerpt;
        if ( '' == $pietergoosen_excerpt ) {

            $pietergoosen_excerpt = get_the_content('');
            $pietergoosen_excerpt = strip_shortcodes( $pietergoosen_excerpt );
            $pietergoosen_excerpt = apply_filters('the_content', $pietergoosen_excerpt);
            $pietergoosen_excerpt = str_replace(']]>', ']]&gt;', $pietergoosen_excerpt);

            //Set the excerpt word count and only break after sentence is complete.
                $excerpt_word_count = 75;
                $excerpt_length = apply_filters('excerpt_length', $excerpt_word_count); 
                $tokens = array();
                $excerptOutput = '';
                $count = 0;

                // Divide the string into tokens; HTML tags, or words, followed by any whitespace
                preg_match_all('/(<[^>]+>|[^<>\s]+)\s*/u', $pietergoosen_excerpt, $tokens);

                foreach ($tokens[0] as $token) { 

                    if ($count >= $excerpt_word_count && preg_match('/[\?\.\!]\s*$/uS', $token)) { 
                    // Limit reached, continue until  ? . or ! occur at the end
                        $excerptOutput .= trim($token);
                        break;
                    }

                    // Add words to complete sentence
                    $count++;

                    // Append what's left of the token
                    $excerptOutput .= $token;
                }

            $pietergoosen_excerpt = trim(force_balance_tags($excerptOutput));

                $excerpt_end = ' <a href="'. esc_url( get_permalink() ) . '">' . '&nbsp;&raquo;&nbsp;' . sprintf(__( 'Read more about: %s &nbsp;&raquo;', 'pietergoosen' ), get_the_title()) . '</a>'; 
                $excerpt_more = apply_filters('excerpt_more', ' ' . $excerpt_end); 

                //$pos = strrpos($pietergoosen_excerpt, '</');
                //if ($pos !== false)
                // Inside last HTML tag
                //$pietergoosen_excerpt = substr_replace($pietergoosen_excerpt, $excerpt_end, $pos, 0);
                //else
                // After the content
                $pietergoosen_excerpt .= $excerpt_end;

            return $pietergoosen_excerpt;   

        }
        return apply_filters('pietergoosen_custom_wp_trim_excerpt', $pietergoosen_excerpt, $raw_excerpt);
    }

endif; 

remove_filter('get_the_excerpt', 'wp_trim_excerpt');
add_filter('get_the_excerpt', 'pietergoosen_custom_wp_trim_excerpt');
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone is using the answer, word of advice: This will ruin the Advanced Custom Fields. ACF also invokes `wp_insert_post_data` when creating or updating a field, but the `$data` variable is not the same, and will result in the ACF field name to become some unreadable gibberish, which results in not being able to use the field.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a different solution, which uses Wordpress in-built wp_trim_words() function to determine roughly how long the text should be, and then truncates the text at the end of that sentence (a little longer than the number of words specified).

Usage:   **echo im_trim_sentences($very_long_text, 90);**

A custom "strpos_array()" function has also been included in this answer, because PHP's strpos() function only accepts a string as the $needle, but we want to search for different sentence endings (full stop, or exclamation mark, etc).

```
function strpos_array($haystack, $needles, $offset = 0) {
    if (is_array($needles)) {
        $positions = array();
        foreach ($needles as $str) {
            $pos = strpos($haystack, $str, $offset);
            if ($pos !== false) {
                $positions[] = $pos;
            }
        }
        return (count($positions) ? min($positions): false);
    } else {
        return strpos($haystack, $needles, $offset);
    }
}

function im_trim_sentences($text, $number_of_words = 55, $more = null) {
    $allowed_end = array('.', '!', '?', '...');
    $text_no_html = strip_tags($text);
    $trimmed_text = wp_trim_words($text, $number_of_words, $more);
    $trimmed_text_length = strlen($trimmed_text);
    $sentence_end_position = strpos_array($text_no_html, $allowed_end, $trimmed_text_length);
    $text_with_html = (($sentence_end_position !== false) ? substr($text_no_html, 0, ($sentence_end_position + 1)) : $trimmed_text);
    return wpautop($text_with_html);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what works for me (WP version 6.2.2):

```php
function truncateBySentence($content, $limit) {
    if (strlen($content) <= $limit) return $content;

    $sentences = preg_split('/(?<=[.!?])\s+/', $content);
    $result = "";

    foreach ($sentences as $sentence) {
        if (strlen($result . $sentence) > $limit) {
            break;
        }
        $result .= $sentence . " ";
    }

    return rtrim($result) . "..";
}

// cut off the excerpt at the end of a sentence, not randomly
add_filter('get_the_excerpt', function($excerpt, $post) {
    // remove all <pre> blocks completely, we don't want code in our excerpts (this may be specific to my blog content)
    $content = preg_replace('/<pre.*?>.*?<\/pre>/si', '', $post->post_content);

    // remove all HTML so we can work with plain old text when generating excerpts
    $content = strip_tags($content);

    $target_length = 750;
    $content = truncateBySentence($content, $target_length);

    // remove all newlines to avoid line breaks in the excerpt
    $content = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $content);

    return $content;
}, 1, 2);
```