# Limit the_excerpt in the first point (.) of the sentence

Tags: excerpt, limit

I would like to filter the function `the_excerpt` to stop to find the first endpoint.

Ex: "This is the article summary which ends at the endpoint with a full-stop."

Any idea is welcome.

Comment: Not sure if this is a duplicate, but read [this](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/108826/how-to-end-the-excerpt-with-a-sentence-rather-than-a-word/108857#108857) should be useful

Comment: Thank you for having edited @Mayeenul Islam. By Google translator may not have expressed in the best way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, please make sure you understand [the difference between `the_excerpt` and `the_content`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_excerpt#the_excerpt.28.29_vs._the_content.28.29). You are asking about `the_excerpt` but I suspect that you might actually mean `the_content`. That said...

You can filter the `the_excerpt` function with [a filter of the same name](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.6.1/wp-includes/post-template.php#L254).

```
add_filter(
  'the_excerpt',
  function ($excerpt) {
    return substr($excerpt,0,strpos($excerpt,'.')+1);
  }
);
```