# Show first sentence of blog post in blog roll

Tags: blog

Is there a known way to show the very first sentence of the content of a blog post? I know I can use `the_excerpt();` but client has a strange requirement to show only the first sentence. If there is a known method for this that would be great to know. I appreciate it.

Comment: Did you try this? http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/108826/how-to-end-the-excerpt-with-a-sentence-rather-than-a-word

Comment: i read that and tried it. for one it doesn't work for me; for two i want this to be first sentence of the content and not excerpt. if i am forcing user to type in an excerpt that they would just type in the first sentence and i wouldn't need all of this.

Comment: What _exact_ part do you have issue with? Retrieving content? Cutting down to a first sentence?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to cut off a string after the first full stop you could use something like this:

```
$the-content = "This is the first sentence. And this is the second";
$cut-in-two = explode('.', $the-content, 2);
$first-sentence = $cut-in-two[0];
```

Comment: curious how this would work with a dynamic the_content();

Comment: @HollerTrain. Do you mean you're manipulating the result of `the_content()` with javascript on the user end? Then it won't work, obviously. However, if you're building a page on the server end with php, `get_the_content()` gives a string that can be manipulated as shown. You'd have to replace the first line with `$the-content = get_the_content();`