# End excerpt at the end of the sentence

Tags: filters, excerpt

I need to create an excerpt that doesn't stop with an orphan word such as:

*All I’ve got to do is pass as an ordinary human being. Simple. What could possibly go wrong? Did I mention we have comfy chairs? I’m the Doctor, I’m worse than everyone’s aunt. catches himself And that is not how I’m introducing myself.You hit me with a cricket bat. It’s more...Read More*

I need it to end with *"You hit me with a cricket bat"* (the last complete sentence is where I want it to stop).

I found this on [another post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/108857/5549):

```
add_filter('get_the_excerpt', 'end_with_sentence');

function end_with_sentence($excerpt) {
  $allowed_end = array('.', '!', '?', '...');
  $exc = explode( ' ', $excerpt );
  $found = false;
  $last = '';
  while ( ! $found && ! empty($exc) ) { 
    $last = array_pop($exc);
    $end = strrev( $last );
    $found = in_array( $end{0}, $allowed_end );
  }
  return (! empty($exc)) ? $excerpt : rtrim(implode(' ', $exc) . ' ' .$last);
}
```

and then I add this to my template:

```
<?php get_the_excerpt(); ?>
```

But it doesn't seem to work. It doesn't display anything.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: echo get_the_excerpt();

Comment: @Nath that worked. I forgot that I had to echo it. thanks. Post this as the answer and I will accept .

Comment: @agon024 did you try my function below? It's much cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

Use this function instead. Then put `the_excerpt();` in your template.

```
/**
 * Find the last period in the excerpt and remove everything after it.
 * If no period is found, just return the entire excerpt.
 *
 * @param string $excerpt The post excerpt.
 */
function end_with_sentence( $excerpt ) {

  if ( ( $pos = mb_strrpos( $excerpt, '.' ) ) !== false ) {
    $excerpt = substr( $excerpt, 0, $pos + 1 );
  }

  return $excerpt;
}
add_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'end_with_sentence' );
```

Comment: that only removes the "...Read More >>" It still leaves an sentence orphan.

Comment: You must be using a custom [excerpt_more](https://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Read_More#Modify_the_Read_More_text_when_using_the_the_excerpt.28.29) filter to modify the standard "Read More" or [...] output to "...Read More". If you remove the three dots, it'll work.

Answer (score 1):

This will take anything you throw at it ;-)  Plus, it's easy to read (kidding, I'm just kidding).

P.S. must be PHP 5.4 or greater...

```
function end_with_sentence( $excerpt ) {
    // change the '...' to whatever your "read more" string is; default in WP is '...'
    $excerpt = explode( '(#~)', str_replace( ['...','? ','! ','. '], ['($/s$/)','?(#~)','!(#~)','. (#~)'], preg_replace( '!\s+!', ' ', trim( $excerpt ) ) ) );
    return ( !strpos( end( $excerpt ), '($/s$/)' ) ) ? implode( ' ', $excerpt ) : implode( ' ', array_slice( $excerpt, 0, -1 ) );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to `echo` the function `get_the_excerpt()`.

So in your template use:

```
echo get_the_excerpt();
```