# Cutting off excerpt with first sentence

Tags: filters, excerpt

I'm trying to end my excerpts with the first sentence. I had attempted the solutions I found on this website, including **each** function + add_filter from these posts:

[How to end the excerpt with a sentence rather than a word?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/108826/how-to-end-the-excerpt-with-a-sentence-rather-than-a-word)

and

[End excerpt at the end of the sentence](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/241828/end-excerpt-at-the-end-of-the-sentence)

It hasn't worked. I had checked that the filter is applied by adding the function:

```
function print_filters_for( $hook = '' ) {
global $wp_filter;
if( empty( $hook ) || !isset( $wp_filter[$hook] ) )
    return;

print '<pre>';
print_r( $wp_filter[$hook] );
print '</pre>';
}
```

and calling it on the templates. It shows up. I had tried switching the order that it's applied with the generic wp_trim_excerpt by adding the $priority argument, but it doesn't make the difference: excerpts are still trimmed by number of words. If it makes a difference, I'm using Divi and making a child theme.

Does anyone know what may be the problem?

Comment: please post the code you tried.

Answer (score 0):

Try the solution by @Pieter Goosen i found for me it was the best solution, and it easy to customise.

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'pietergoosen_custom_wp_trim_excerpt' ) ) : 

    function pietergoosen_custom_wp_trim_excerpt($pietergoosen_excerpt) {
    global $post;
    $raw_excerpt = $pietergoosen_excerpt;
        if ( '' == $pietergoosen_excerpt ) {

            $pietergoosen_excerpt = get_the_content('');
            $pietergoosen_excerpt = strip_shortcodes( $pietergoosen_excerpt );
            $pietergoosen_excerpt = apply_filters('the_content', $pietergoosen_excerpt);
            $pietergoosen_excerpt = str_replace(']]>', ']]&gt;', $pietergoosen_excerpt);

            //Set the excerpt word count and only break after sentence is complete.
                $excerpt_word_count = 75;
                $excerpt_length = apply_filters('excerpt_length', $excerpt_word_count); 
                $tokens = array();
                $excerptOutput = '';
                $count = 0;

                // Divide the string into tokens; HTML tags, or words, followed by any whitespace
                preg_match_all('/(<[^>]+>|[^<>\s]+)\s*/u', $pietergoosen_excerpt, $tokens);

                foreach ($tokens[0] as $token) { 

                    if ($count >= $excerpt_word_count && preg_match('/[\?\.\!]\s*$/uS', $token)) { 
                    // Limit reached, continue until  ? . or ! occur at the end
                        $excerptOutput .= trim($token);
                        break;
                    }

                    // Add words to complete sentence
                    $count++;

                    // Append what's left of the token
                    $excerptOutput .= $token;
                }

            $pietergoosen_excerpt = trim(force_balance_tags($excerptOutput));

                $excerpt_end = ' <a href="'. esc_url( get_permalink() ) . '">' . '&nbsp;&raquo;&nbsp;' . sprintf(__( 'Read more about: %s &nbsp;&raquo;', 'pietergoosen' ), get_the_title()) . '</a>'; 
                $excerpt_more = apply_filters('excerpt_more', ' ' . $excerpt_end); 

                //$pos = strrpos($pietergoosen_excerpt, '</');
                //if ($pos !== false)
                // Inside last HTML tag
                //$pietergoosen_excerpt = substr_replace($pietergoosen_excerpt, $excerpt_end, $pos, 0);
                //else
                // After the content
                $pietergoosen_excerpt .= $excerpt_end;

            return $pietergoosen_excerpt;   

        }
        return apply_filters('pietergoosen_custom_wp_trim_excerpt', $pietergoosen_excerpt, $raw_excerpt);
    }

endif; 

remove_filter('get_the_excerpt', 'wp_trim_excerpt');
add_filter('get_the_excerpt', 'pietergoosen_custom_wp_trim_excerpt');
```